# use-package org-mode :hook is being ignored

Tags: org-mode, hooks, use-package

I'm currently running this version of Emacs:

```
GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.7) of 2019-04-11, modified by Debian
```

I'm attempting to use [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) to configure the latest version of org-mode, and not the one that comes with Emacs. My initial attempt at configuration used `:hook` directive (commented out in the elisp code below) does not work, as the resulting value of `org-mode-hook` does not have `my-org-mode-hook` at all (the actual value is shown later on):

```
;; Define org and melpa as package sources, and install `use-package' if it's
;; not already there. Origination:
;; https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/5sx7j0/how_do_i_get_usepackage_to_ignore_the_bundled/
;; Here, I *DO* actually desire automatic updating of the latest packages in this
;; case (specifically org-mode which receives frequent updates.
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
;; Ensure that "org" and "melpa" are found first in this order (higher numbers are higher priority):
(when (>= emacs-major-version 25) (setq package-archive-priorities '(("org" . 3)
                                 ("melpa" . 2)
                                 ("gnu" . 1))))
;; This is the key!! --> " The symbol ‘all’ says to load the latest installed
;; versions of all packages not specified by other elements." and for org-mode,
;; this means always get that latest version.
(setq package-load-list '(all))
(package-initialize)
;; Not sure why we need this:
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
;; Install use-package:
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))
;; Load org mode early to ensure that the orgmode ELPA version gets picked up, not the
;; shipped version.
;;
;;   Reference https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#package-installation
;;
(require 'use-package-ensure)
(setq use-package-always-ensure t)
;;
;; Now the configuration for org-mode:
;;
(use-package org
  ;; Install both org and "contrib"-uted org-related packages:
  :ensure org-plus-contrib
  :pin org
  ;;
  ;; This seems to be correct way to add my hook function to org-mode-hook, but
  ;; it does not show up in the value of org-mode-hook, so I commented it out in
  ;; favor of the forced use of add-hook inside :config, later:
  ;;
  ;;    :hook #'my-org-mode-hook
  ;;
  :config
  ;;
  ;; This seems to be the only way to get my hook function to be added, as the
  ;; :hook directive is ignored or obliterated by something else:
  ;;
  (add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-org-mode-hook))
```

When try to use `:hook` that is commented out above (and of course also commenting out the call to `add-hook`), I get this for the final value after opening up a `.org` file:

```
org-mode-hook is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.
Its value is shown below.

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.

Documentation:
Mode hook for Org mode, run after the mode was turned on.

You can customize this variable.

Value:
(#f(compiled-function
()
#<bytecode 0x1684c2d>)
   #f(compiled-function
  ()
  #<bytecode 0x1ab413d>)
   org-babel-result-hide-spec org-babel-hide-all-hashes #f(compiled-function
                           ()
                           #<bytecode 0x1ae75e1>)
   org-eldoc-load)
Original value was nil
```

As seen above, the `my-org-mode-hook` function is not in the value. My understanding is that `use-package` should add it there (per [use-package Hooks section](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#hooks)) but does not, and I have to force it with the explicit call to `add-hook`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue why yours didn't work, maybe use-package is not correctly identifying that it should attach to the 'org-mode-hook. However, I managed to add my own hook to enable visual-line-mode, in the other alternative way documented to insert hooks:

```
(use-package org
 ;; Specify my hook to add to org-mode-hook (remove the -hook suffix):
 :hook (org-mode . (lambda () (visual-line-mode)))
```

In your case it would be:

```
(use-package org 
 ; again, remove `-hook` from org-mode-hook:
 :hook (org-mode . '#my-org-mode-hook))
```

I think that way will work for you also, as the hook to which this is added is explicit.